# Is there a way to add two remotes to git

Tags: git, github, heroku

I want to push my code into GitHub and Heroku with git, is it possible to define two remotes and push with a single command?

Comment: If you're using Heroku you likely already *have* two remotes; see `git remote -v`. `commit` generally doesn't care about remotes.

Comment: thanks man.. got a better idea of git

Comment: You don’t commit to a remote. Instead you commit to a local repo and push those commits to a remote, which is just another repo.

Comment: actually, I misused the commit instead of push, thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @MostafaEsmaeili you’re welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, because **heroku uses different git remote repository** for your deployments, think your remote origin(github) is development repository and remote heroku as a production repository. But good news, Github has an integration with heroku! See at [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration)

1. You can integrate your github repository to heroku
2. Update on **github repo master branch** you can **trigger to update heroku remote master branch** as well, so you dont need to push two remote repositories(origin and heroku)

Comment: that's just awsome, it just takes some seconds for heroku to update after pushing to gituhb.